# Expand to fit in an overflowed container

Tags: html, css

I have several divs in a container div with overflow set to auto. I need to expand the width of all divs to fit the overflowed width of the container.

Here is a very simple example:

http://jsfiddle.net/DDtuM/2/

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether this is possible purely using HTML and CSS, but I wrote jquery to do this.

It simply finds the max width of all the inner divs and then sets the value of all inner divs to max.

Find the code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/DDtuM/5/

Answer (score 2):

try adding `display: table;` to #container

see: http://jsfiddle.net/DDtuM/13/

Drawback: older versions of IE do not support display: table.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like it expands the container width. I need to keep the container width fixed.